# Adding an image to tree view in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a treeview control in wpf..i need to add an image at evry node.how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have unique images for each node, you can do something like:

```
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <Image Source="/WpfApplication2;component/folder.png" Height="25" Width="25"/>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <Image Source="/WpfApplication2;component/folder1.png" Height="25" Width="25"/>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <Image Source="/WpfApplication2;component/folder2.png" Height="25" Width="25"/>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <Image Source="/WpfApplication2;component/folder3.png" Height="25" Width="25"/>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

or, if you want to have the same image for each node, you can do something like this:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Image Source="/WpfApplication2;component/folder.png" Height="25" Width="25" x:Key="FolderIcon" x:Shared="false"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="FolderIcon"/>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="FolderIcon"/>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="FolderIcon"/>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="FolderIcon"/>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE** to answer the following question: "how can i change the image/icon on clicking/expanding the node"

Here is a quick and dirty solution.

Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Image Source="/WpfApplication2;component/folder.png" Height="25" Width="25" x:Key="FolderIcon" x:Shared="false"/>
    <Image Source="/WpfApplication2;component/folderOpened.jpg" Height="25" Width="25" x:Key="FolderOpenIcon" x:Shared="false"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="itemExpanded" Name="treeViewItem">
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="FolderIcon"/>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem/>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

C# / Code-behind

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void itemExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeViewItem.IsExpanded)
        {
            treeViewItem.Header = FindResource("FolderIcon");
        }
        else
        {
            treeViewItem.Header = FindResource("FolderOpenIcon");
        }          
    }
}
```

You can also accomplish this using the "Expanded" event as well. If you want eliminate "code-behind" you can also do this using a Command or Converter.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for the solution..But I have one more concerns..how can i change the image/icon on clicking/expanding the node..Is this possible..For eg..I have a folder Icon at first at the tree node..now when i click the node,or expand it,the image should change to other icon.Kindly help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move image to resource section and set x:Shared="False":

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
   <Image Source="links.png" x:Key="imgLinks" x:Shared="False"/>
   ```
2. Use it in template:`<StaticResource ResourceKey="imgLinks"/>`